# SQL Server Query -- How to continue on error

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-delete

I have a table containing thousands of fields and some of them were duplicated due to customer's failure and I need to fix it.
I can find them and delete them row by row, but I am looking for a faster work around.

As some of these are related to other tables, they can not be deleted directly without taking care of the relation. I wand to first delete those are not included in the relationship by running a simple DELETE command without any conditions, so all unrelated rows will be deleted and rest of them can be done rapidly.

Here is the question, What can I do to skip errors and delete all unrelated rows?
Currently when I run the query, it stops when the first related ID is found.(The conflict occurred in database ....)

Any suggestions?

Comment: left join blah .... where something on right side is null...

Comment: Your table structure and example data would help.

Comment: you need try catch. look at this http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms179296(v=sql.105).aspx

Comment: I want to do it in single DELETE query. no need to consider the other table to use left join or Outer join, etc.
I assume there should be something like "CONTINUE ON ERROR" to be set, am I wrong?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use an outer join for the deletion (where the related table is the other side of the join), where the ID is null in the outer join, it's safe to delete as you won't get a constraint violation.

However, huge, unbounded deletions sounds like a massive risk to me, ensure you have BACKUPS.

Comment: There are more than one table with relation to this table. 
I assume there should be something like "CONTINUE ON ERROR" to be set, am I wrong?

Comment: Well, you could use multiple outer joins, then where it's null for ALL outer join ids, you have a non-match. I don't believe there's a continue on error for SQL Server. Maybe there is, but try to use a more elegant solution, ignoring errors is a botch.